# How can I set up a Black Ops LAN party?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-black-ops

Alright, here's my situation. I have Internet, and play Black Ops on my Playstation 3.
However, as the PSN network is down right now, I'd like to play with my brother, who's downstairs with another PS3 and a copy of Call of Duty.  Shouldn't my system allow me to play with him via our local area network, through our router? Any help solving this problem would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2011/4/25/

Comment: Does Black Ops support LAN?

Comment: @Arkive, Technically no. It supports local games, but you still need to be able to connect to the host. With PSN down, you are teh lose (as far as I know).

Comment: Do you have 2 routers?

Answer (score 2):

It absolutly works.  Create and start a game on one of the systems.  On the second system search for the game.  I have been playing Black Ops through a LAN connection for a week now!!!